# SQLite: SELECT and DELETE

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 data base in raspberry-pi, I have an script which sends data to the mongo db server. As soon as I send the data to the mongoDB I want to delete the row. But I am not able to do that, here is the code for the following

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var sqlDB = new sqlite3.Database('Table23.db');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://192.168.0.87:27017';
var winston = require('winston');
var id_1;
winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
winston.add(
    winston.transports.File, {
    filename: 'error.log',
    level: 'info',
    json: true,
    timestamp: true,
    handleException: true
  }
);    
sqlDB.serialize(function() {
     sqlDB.each("SELECT * FROM Table23", function(err, row) {
        var data = {
            type: row.TYPE,
            id: row.ID,
            place: row.Place
        };
    var id = data.id;
    id_1 = id;
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) {
                winston.error('Unable to connect'+ err);
            } else {
                console.log('Connection successful');
                var collection = db.collection('testdb');
                collection.insert([data], function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        winston.error(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Inserted %d documents into the "Testdb" collection. The documents inserted with "_id" are:', result.length, result);
                    }
                    db.close();
                });
            }
            });

        sqlDB.run("DELETE FROM Table23 WHERE id=(?)",[id_1], function(err) {
            if(err){
                winston.error(err);
            }
            else{
                console.log("Successful");
            }

        });
    });
});
sqlDB.close();
```

When I run this I get a "errno":21,"code":"SQLITE_MISUSE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the completion callback of the `each` function to carry out the next command. Then close the database **after** the delete has been completed.

```
var sqlDB = new sqlite3.Database('./abcd')
var id_1;

sqlDB.serialize(() => {
    sqlDB.serialize(() => {
        var n = 0;
        sqlDB.each("SELECT * FROM Table23", function(err, row, i) {
            let data = {
                type: row.TYPE,
                id: row.ID,
                place: row.Place
            };
            var id = data.id;
            id_1 = id;
        }, ()=> {

            sqlDB.run("DELETE FROM Table23 WHERE id=(?)", id_1, function(err) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Successful");
                }
                sqlDB.close();
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried the method you suggested, there is no error but nothing gets deleted from the database. I do not understand why. Any idea why?

Comment: @AnkKhandelwal: Just updated answers as you were replying. Previous answer was not detailed enough. This works. Try it and let me know!

Comment: great! glad to help :)